# Can't destroy x-editable select2

Tags: jquery, x-editable

I'm using x-editable along with select2. When my page changed the dynamic data, I found I have to destroy all my x-editable instances and reinitialize them. It works on everything else except my 1 select2 field.

Here's how I init that select2

```
$('#iname1').editable({
                    url: 'ajax/updateInsuranceProvider.php',
                    value: p.ikey1, //use 11 for testing 
                    mode: 'inline',
                    params: {field: "ikey1"},
                    source: 'ajax/lookupProviders.php',
                    select2: {
                        width: '330px',
                        placeholder: 'Select Provider',
                        allowClear: false,
                        formatResult: function (provider) {
                            return provider.iname;
                        },
                        formatSelection: function (provider) {
                            return provider.iname;
                        },
                        initSelection: function (element, callback) {
                            return $.get('ajax/loadProvider.php', { provider: element.val() }, function (data) {
                                callback(data);
                            }, 'json'); //added dataType
                        }
                    }
                });
```

When I call $('#iname1').editable("destroy") I get

```
Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

Here is the line of code that is causing that error:

```
destroy: function() {
        if(this.$input.data('select2')) {
            this.$input.select2('destroy');
        }
    }
```

Apparently $input is not set. This is in the file jquery-editable-poshytip.js

Comment: Do u find a solution ?